# AJAX call to get IDs, then insert IDs in new AJAX call for each ID

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, function

I hope the title gave somewhat of an explanation of what I'm trying to do. I'm lost on the whole subject, so please be patient with me here  :)

I'm using the following to retrieve individual IDs of all objects in a specific category

```
function mba(user, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    console.log(hash);
    return 'Basic ' + hash;
}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://domain.com/category?strip=true&q=currentCatId='LONG_UNIQUE_ID'&fields=id",
    type: "GET",

    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", mba("USER", "PASS"));
    },

    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(status + " - " + error);
    }
});
```

And this works fine. What I need help under standing is, once this is done, I need each ID retrieved to be inserted into a new call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://domain.com/category/"+ INDIVIDUAL_IDS_SHOULD_GO_HERE +"?strip=true&expand=true&collections=something,something2",
    type: "GET",

    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", mba("USER", "PASS"));
    },

    success: function(data){
        $(".myCont").loadTemplate("#myTemp", data);
},

    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(status + " - " + error);
}
```

});

So the first call gets the all the IDs of each object in that specific category. But then I need extended information on each object, which can only be retrieved by giving a unique ID in the second call (for each ID retrieved in the first call).

I understand that the code I've presented here is incorrect. I need to understand (and get it right) how this should be done.

The "$(".myCont").loadTemplate("#myTemp", data);" part is for a [JQueryTemplate](http://codepb.github.io/jquery-template/index.html). So this is what I use to present the actual (extended) data collected from each object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your **first call** you CAN (although there are better ways) just add a 'success' parameter and add your second ajax call in there

```
 success: function(data){
    //pseudo code

 for each data
 INDIVIDUAL_IDS_SHOULD_GO_HERE = this data
 ajax call with that INDIVIDUAL_ID
 end for each data
 }
```

it is hard to comment as I am guessing what is being returned by the first call but as you say 'id **s**' I am guessing you can iterate through them for subsequent calls.

However I would probably (depending on circumstances) write a call that runs a php script to call each of the URLs and return a JSON object with the results as one data set - less calls on the client side = less traffic and overall a better experience (especially if they were on a mobile - 10 calls COULD take ages).